# How can I print these html tags as text with lxml?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, lxml

So I have a webpage that has a large list of links. They are all contained inside `<li>` tags.

The `<li>` tags are inside a `<ol>` tag inside a `<div>` and so on like this:

```
html --> body --> table --> tbody --> tr --> td --> table --> tbody --> tr --> td --> div --> ol
```

And then the `<li>` tags are inside the `<ol>`.

How can I use `lxml` in Python to print the `<li>` tags' html as text?

Comment: Do you have to use lxml?  Does the list (ol), or table have an ID assigned to it, or is there only one table in the document?

Comment: Same question as @mdadm. I would use BeautifulSoup (which does in fact USE lxml)

Comment: Please provide an actual HTML example. It's not just about describing your problem, but also about providing people answering your question the means to test their solutions.

Comment: There are several tables in the page. @mdadm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup` (which builds on the `lxml` library)

```
import bs4

text = """<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <table>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <div>
           <ol>
            <li>
             <a href="test.html" title="test title">Link Text</a>
             <a href="test2.html" title="test title 2">Link2 Text</a>
            </li>
           </ol>
          </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)

listitems = soup.select("table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > ol > li")
tags = [tag for tag in listitems[0] if isinstance(tag,bs4.element.Tag)]
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)

# OUTPUT
# <a href="test.html" title="test title">Link Text</a>
# <a href="test2.html" title="test title 2">Link2 Text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below should do it in lxml, however, beautiful soup will probably be a much better solution and handle malformed HTML much better.

```
import lxml.etree as etree

tree = etree.parse(open("test.html"))
for li in tree.iterfind(".//td/div/ol/li"):
    print etree.tostring(li[0])
```

I'll edit with a beautifulsoup answer in a minute. **EDIT**: See Adam's solution.